# Removing extra padding around text

Tags: css

I have a `div`. And I'm trying to pad around the text 5px — no more, no less — but there's some extra spacing being thrown in there, like my browser is laughing in my face at my futile attempts to get this to do what I want it to do.

#### Here's the CSS I'm using:

```
div{
    font-family:'Arial', sans-serif;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

#### And here's my HTML:

```
<div>
    Sort By:
    <select>
        <option>Customer</option>
    </select>
    Search Customer:
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

(No styling's going on for the `input` and `select` fields, by the way.)

#### And here's the output I'm getting in my browser window

(highlighted with Chrome's developer console to give you an idea of the extra spacing going on):

[html output http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/2438/padding.png](http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/2438/padding.png)

Wait a second, what's going on there?  I've got 5px of padding all around, and then this weird *inner padding* going on.  I measured it in an image editor, and that extra *padding* or whatever I should be calling it is adding an additional 8px of padding, top and bottom.

Thought it might be a `line-height` problem — so I set that to 0.  Didn't change a thing.  Tried setting it to a negative number.  Didn't work, either;  in fact, Chrome wanted nothing to do with that and gave me an error.

So what's this extra stuff doing here?  Does it have a name?  Can I shrink it?  I want exactly 5px of space around those letters, not a nearly-three-times-as-much 13px.

I appreciate the help — thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this might sound crazy but - the css for div - is there a div above it? as the css would be applied to this as well...

Comment: Thanks for your well-written question. Though it's perhaps a _little_ friendly!

Comment: which browser (and version) are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 11, but it turned out the text input was just stretching that out a little bit.  Stupid, I know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The form elements may be expanding the containing element. It's hard to tell, since you didn't include them in your screenshot for some reason.

If you set `overflow: hidden` on your `div`, you may see this behaviour stop. Of course, you probably don't want this; you may be better off trying to manually set the height of those form elements, and ensure that they have `margin: 0` set.

Comment: Right on.  It was the input field that was causing the problem.  Whoops.  I don't even know why I didn't notice that.  Thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

Try also removing any `margin` from the `<select>` element:

```
select {
    margin: 0;
}
```

This could also be due to invisible text nodes. Try removing *all* whitespace from your HTML when you want pixel precision:

```
<div>Sort By:<select>
    <!-- in here whitespace won't matter -->
    <option>Customer</option>
</select>Search Customer:<input type="text"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding:

```
body{
    margin:0px !important;
    }
```

Comment: .. and in doing so, affect every element on the page?